# Как выбрать потомков от родителя в jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, выборка

Подскажите, пожалуйста самый простой способ выбрать 3-х потомков от одинаковых родителей. Приведу пример

```js
$(".block").children(":lt(3)").wrapAll("<div class='view_list__leftSide' />");
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.view_list__leftSide {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <span>Three</span>
  <p>Four</p>
  <button>Five</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p class="foo">Six</p>
  <a href="">Seven</a>
  <span>Eight</span>
  <div class="bl_text">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Есть некие блоки в середине которых находятся некий неоднородный контент. Задача - Как первых трёх потомков обернуть в div оббертку с нужным классом ? Возможно ли это сделать без циклов? ПС. Мой пример отрабатывает только на первом блоке и останавливается

Comment: делайте через `$('.block).each(....)`, вам изменения вносить надо в каждую отдельную ветку дерева. нет особого смысла это пытаться объединить. да и не получится

Comment: $('.block).each(....) чего? как выбрать первых три элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваш пример не обрабатывает первый блок и останаливается. Он просто сначала сваливает всех потомков в один список, а потом из них выбирает первые три.

но чем плох вариант с циклами,  почему вы хотите их избежать?

```
$(".block").each(function(idx, v){ 
     $(v).children(":lt(3)").wrapAll("<div class='view_list__leftSide' />");
})
```

---

*Для некоторых задач (например, изменить стиль, добавить класс и т.п. не требующих операций с DOM), можно было бы перечислить первые 3 элемента каждого блока таким образом:*

```
$(".block > :nth-child(1), .block > :nth-child(2), .block > :nth-child(3)")
```

*и выполнить нужные действия. Но когда речь идет об обертке во внешний html это не прокатывает. Ибо все выбранные элементы оборачиваются в общий див и переносятся в первый `.block`.*

---

```js
$(".block").each(function(idx, v){
  $(v).children(":lt(3)").wrapAll("<div class='view_list__leftSide' />");
  console.log( $(v).html());
});
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.view_list__leftSide {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <span>Three</span>
  <p>Four</p>
  <button>Five</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p class="foo">Six</p>
  <a href="">Seven</a>
  <span>Eight</span>
  <div class="bl_text">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Метод   $(".block").each(function(idx, v){ 
     $(v).children(":lt(3)").wrap("<div class='view_list__leftSide' />");
})                                                                                                                     не подходит, он вокруг каждого элемента создает оббертку, а необходимо что б первые три элемента заворачивало в Одну оббертку

Comment: @BlackStar1991 не правда, дополнил ответ, выполните код, в консоли будет html. все три элемента заворачиваются в один див

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x0mLny5f/

Comment: @BlackStar1991 обратите внимание на разницу в `wrapAll` и `wrap`

Comment: да, что-то в верхнем коде у меня было (`wrap`), а не как в примере внизу `wrapAll`, изменил

Comment: Спасибо, помогло